# multiple condition then creating new column

Tags: r, subset, selection, dplyr

I have a dataset with two columns, I need to create a third column carries conditions on first one and second one.

```
set.seed(1)
x1=(sample(1:10, 100,replace=T))
y1=sample(seq(1,10,0.1),100,replace=T)

z=cbind(x1,y1)
unique(as.data.frame(z)$x1)
z%>%as.data.frame()%>%dplyr::filter(x1==3)

table(x1)
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 7  6 11 14 14  5 11 15 11  6 

> z%>%as.data.frame()%>%dplyr::filter(x1==3)
   x1   y1
1   3  6.9
2   3  9.5
3   3 10.0
4   3  5.6
5   3  4.1
6   3  2.5
7   3  5.3
8   3  9.5
9   3  5.5
10  3  8.9
11  3  1.2
```

for example when I filter x==3 then y1 values can be seen, I need to write 1 on 11th row, rest will be 0. I need to find a minimum in that column. My original dataset has 43545 rows but only 638 unique numbers like x1. table x1 shows that 1 repeated 7 times but in my dataset some have a frequency of 1 some have frequency of 100. I should use case_when but how can I check every y1 to find the smallest to put 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the row with minimal y1 value for each value of x1

```
library(tidyverse)
z %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
      group_by(x1) %>% 
      arrange(y1) %>% # sort values by increasing order within each group
      mutate(flag = ifelse(row_number()==1,1,0)) %>% # create flag for first row in group
      ungroup()
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do. Arrange gave me an error when I tried. But this works. Thanks!

Comment: What's the error with arrange? Maybe adding `library(tidyverse)` before the code would help